# Why would sdi to hdmi work, but not when I convert sdi to hdmi to dvi

Tags: video, hdmi

I am transmitting video over sdi and converting from sdi to hdmi with an aja Hi5. This works, but if I convert that hdmi output into dvi, the output is either not detected, or constantly connects and disconnects without getting a display. This was tested on multiple monitors, and multiple adapters that all work independently. I've also run an hdmi signal booster just in case, which seemed to have no effect. Input is 720p 59.94.

I'm kinda out of ideas for why going from hdmi to dvi breaks everything. My final display is DVI only, which is why I'm going to all this trouble.

Comment: Questions about the use of products, including computing gear, are off topic here.  The handwaving answer is that even though you can get adapter cables these things are not really equivalent, and behave differently in some cases... typically the critical ones, like needing a dev board to render to the monitor you have on hand and were hoping would stand in for the product's display, or worse the one you bought specifically for that goal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what the HDMI source is, but there are two possible options. First, which is true for any HDMI to SDI converter is that the HDMI source might require HDCP protected link which the HDMI to SDI converter cannot possibly provide (legally). Second option (which I have met with Aja SDI to HDMI converters actually) is that the SDI to HDMI converter always uses HDMI protocol (does not switch to DVI protocol when DVI display is connected) and the DVI display is not compatible with HDMI protocol so it cannot display the signal.